# reading .csv file.

Tags: python

I have a .csv file i need to loop over, and then inside a loop, i want to check the value of the next line every iteration. I can't seem to get it to work properly, as it skips the line i was looking ahead in the next iteration.

```
import csv
file_object = open('file.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file_object, delimiter = ';')

for line in reader:
    next_line = reader.next()
    # It now reads the next line and doesn't iterate over it again in the next
    # iteration. However, i want it to still iterate over it in the next iteration.
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of both the current and the next line "manually:"

```
line = reader.next()
for next_line in reader:
    # Do your processing
    line = next_line
# Now do whatever needs to be done with the very last line
```

Comment: Alternatively, ``itertools.tee()`` and ``itertools.zip_longest()``.

Comment: Um' i don't exactly see how this works :d. You first read line1, then start iterating from line2. How does this let me see one line ahead during the iteration and then later iterate over the same line?

Comment: @geekkid You begin with ``line`` as the first line, then when you loop, you iterate and put line 2 into ``next_line``, do what you want, then put line to into ``line``, and realine line 3 into ``next_line``, and it continues, with ``line`` being the current line and ``next_line`` being the line after, til you reach the end. You can then, after the loop, process the last line.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you guys!